# sql not in between two weekdays and times

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that monitors connection process. Now I'm stuck and need to set a proper monitoring for weekday and time range.

The process starts on Sunday 22:00, and goes down for 5 min. at 21:55 - every day to Friday. (not goes up from Friday 21:55 till 22:00 on Sunday)

Below is the SQL Query I tried:

```
IF CASE
       WHEN (100 * DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())) 
                 + DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) 
          BETWEEN 2155 AND 2200   -- Monitoring for whole day, wen connection is up
          AND DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()), (100 * DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())) 
            + DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) 
          NOT BETWEEN (5, 2155) AND (0, 2200) --except trough Friday night to Sunday (weekdays and time).

       THEN 1 ELSE 0   END = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to add some `SELECT` statements into the parts of the case where you were getting the values to range between. Try this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN(100 * DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())) + DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) -- = 731
            BETWEEN 2155 AND 2200   -- Monitoring for whole day, wen connection is up
            AND (
                (
                    SELECT
                        DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())
                ) NOT BETWEEN(5) AND(0)
                AND
                (
                    SELECT
                        (100 * DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())) + DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE())
                ) NOT BETWEEN(2155) AND(2200)
                )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END;
```

The first calculation equals 731 so looking at the query I would except it to return '0' which it does